# SSRS-what is the syntax for the Target Server URL in SSRS2008R2

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

can anyone help me out with the syntax and example for the target server URL in SSRS 2008R2 inorder to deploy my reports??

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if they solved your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

are you deploying to sharepoint or a standalone (native-mode) report server?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155802(v=sql.105).aspx

> 10.In the TargetServerURL text box, type the URL of the target report server. Before you publish a report, you must set this property to a
>   valid report server URL. When publishing to a report server running in
>   native mode, use the URL of the virtual directory of the report server
>   (for example, http://server/reportserver or
>   https://server/reportserver). This is the virtual directory of the
>   report server, not Report Manager.
>
> When publishing to a report server running in SharePoint integrated
>   mode, use a URL to a SharePoint top-level site or subsite. If you do
>   not specify a site, the default top-level site is used (for example,
>   http://servername, http://servername/site or
>   http://servername/site/subsite).