# Error: The specified TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for report server in the deployment settings

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have created a Report Server Project in Visual Studio 2013.  The actual report server was a pre-existing server whose reports were previously populated via the Report Builder tool.  I have downloaded the .RDL files locally and added them to the project under the /Reports folder.

When I try to deploy the reports I am receiving the 'TargetServerURL' is not valid error.  I have researched the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926074/ssrs-what-is-the-syntax-for-the-target-server-url-in-ssrs2008r2/9926264#9926264) and [here](http://alexduggleby.com/2008/07/18/sql-server-reporting-services-2008-tutorial-in-5-minutes-or-how-to-send-my-boss-a-report-from-a-view-quickly/).

I can successfully navigate to http:///Reports_PRODUCTION which displays the reports, and also to http:///ReportServer_PRODUCTION which offers an FTP-view of the report structure.

In the project properties I have set the 'TargetServerURL' to both of these URLs and neither has worked.  I've verified that the target server version is correctly set - SQL Server 2008 R2.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding 3 forward slashes so the url does not show up as a link?

Comment: Yes, there are only two slashes in the actual URL I'm setting for the TargetServerURL property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out something, so that's why I post to this old question.

I had the same problems after starting a new VS2013 SSRS project and tried to deploy to the same RS server, but to a different server.

I kept getting the error: The specified TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for report server in the deployment settings.

After quadruple checking everything,I found that I was changing the ssrs project property on Release mode but in VS 2013 I was deploying the project in Debug mode. After changing the VS 2013 configuration to run as Release it found the right ssrs project settings and deployed fine on first run.

Comment: You life saver. I was fiddling with those earlier which stopped my deployment!

Answer (score 3):

I read these answers and looked in my Configuration Manager (Right click project name > Properties > Configuration Manager > and picked the Server that was configured. It shows up checked like the image. I had been uploading with correct info, just didn't have the configuration fully done on my new project which used files and locations from older project:
[Screenshot of Configuration Manager and Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2uwu.jpg)

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, thanks for the answer, @JustJohn.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at what SSRS thinks the service endpoint is and I bet that is the one you should be using.

1. Open the Sql Server 20XX Reporting Service Configuration Manager. 
   *NOTE : This is found under the Sql Server progam group and maybe in a subfolder.*
2. Select the service instance you want to connect to and click Connect
3. Navigate to the "Web Service Url" Tree List View Item in the list on the left hand side of the window.
4. Note the URLs: value in the "Report Server Web Service URLs" group box at the bottom of the Web Service URL panel. (This is the url you should use to connect with)

NOTE : If this is on a remote server then you will need to http or https to the domain in place of *localhost* or *machine name* if that is how the Report service was set up. If you can not access https:\\MACHINENAME/SSRS from your local machine then simply replace the url with *https:\\www.mymachinenameurl.com/SSRS*

Answer (score 0):

make sure your deployment settings for the configuration you are deploying from are set (deploying in debug, ensure you are referring to debug deployment settings)

Answer (score 0):

trust me I've been there .. Allot
I reached here because I've had the same error, and I was not able to deploy my report .

Anyways, at some point I tried to deploy the report manually by uploading to the library that I've already prepared with the Reporting Content Types, but the datasource was appearing as unknown file types, and couldn't access Manage Data Sources of the report.
tried to run the report hopelessly and noticed the url

```
http://ServerName/PWA/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/PWA/Reports%20Library/Weekly%20Status%20Report.rdl
```

I tried to use the url `http://ServerName/PWA/_layouts/15/ReportServer` as "TargetServerURL" and it worked
for the other properties like the Datasets, reports ... I used the following urls

```
Report: http://ServerName/PWA/Reports%20Library/
DataSets: http://ServerName/PWA/Reports%20Library/Datasets
datasource: http://ServerName/PWA/Reports%20Library/datasource
```

and this was the end of my suffer and was able to deploy correctly and manage every property of the report, datasets, and datasources