# SSRS : The specified report server URL is not valid

Tags: reporting-services

I know there are a lot of posts in SO for this issue but none of them seemed to solve my problem

I m running an SSRS stand-alone (native) report server .

I am using SQLEXPRESS 2014 and Visual Studio 2012 integrated shell for my reports .

The reports are running just fine in the shell , I can browse to the report server and i have set TargetServerURL to : **http://localhost/Reports_SQLEXPRESS** . I have also tried **http://laptopname/Reports_SQLEXPRESS**

When trying to deploy the reports i get the : The specified report server url could not be found . Verify that the syntax of the URL .......

2 questions .

- Why do i get this error ?
- What is the difference between release mode and debug mode mentioned in this question and how do i switch modes? [Error: The specified TargetServerURL is not valid. Specify a valid URL for report server in the deployment settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153308/error-the-specified-targetserverurl-is-not-valid-specify-a-valid-url-for-repor)

Some useful snips of my settings :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using the WebService or WebPortal URL? I think you need to use the on with ReportServer in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As snowlockk suggested, you need to use the Web Service URL. It's hard to tell from the URL what you are using but to check, Run the `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` go to the `Web Service URL` tab and use the URL specified there.

[image]